# Is it possible to drop a unique constraint from a column?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I've tried simply removing the `unique=True` constraint and running

```
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

in the command line but when I run my flask app I'm still getting a `(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed` error.

Is there a simple way to do this with flask-migrate or should I switch to alembic (which I know flask-migrate is just wrapped around)? I would prefer not to drop the entire table. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flask-Migrate, or rather Alembic, will [not autodetect anonymous constraints](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect). But you can create a manual Alembic migration file to drop the constraint.

Create an empty migration file:

```
flask db revision -m 'Drop unique constraint'
```

Edit the file to drop the constraint:

```
def upgrade():
    op.drop_constraint("name_of_constraint", "table_name")

def downgrade():
    op.create_index(...)
```

I suggest you copy the `create_index` from the migration file that created the constraint in the first place, if possible.

Then you can upgrade your database normally:

```
flask db upgrade
```